# Tycho could not find oracle database driver bundle

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, maven, tycho

I observe the following problem. I have a RCP Eclipse Application. Eclipse release is Mars. I would like to use Tycho plugin for building this application. All required bundles were installed in my Eclipse distribution. I'm able to build and export this application (via product file) using Eclipse IDE. When I try to build application using maven I catch error

```
 Cannot resolve project dependencies:                                                                                                         
   Software being installed: com.psl.atom.services 1.0.0.qualifier                                                                            
   Missing requirement: com.psl.atom.services 1.0.0.qualifier requires 'bundle oracle.database.driver.11 8.6.0' but it could not be found
```

So problem is maven cannot find oracle driver bundle. As mentioned above this bundle is installed in my Eclipse. The repositories that were used for installing oracle bundle to Eclipse IDE were included in target file.
Can anybody help me to resolve this problem? How can I correctly get Oracle bundle. Due to license problem this bundle are stored in another repository, not in Maven Central.
By the way Eclipse says that Database tools were installed from

```
<repository location="http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.2.1.2/mars/repository" />
```

Thank you in advance
Alexander

my parent maven is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>xxx.xxx.xxx</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <artifactId>xxx.xxx.xxx.parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <properties>
        <tycho-version>0.23.1</tycho-version>
        <xtextVersion>2.9.1</xtextVersion>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>windows-1251</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <xxx.xxx.xxx.services.version>1.0.0</xxx.xxx.xxx.services.version>
    </properties>
    <modules>
        <module>xxx.xxx.xxx</module>
        <module>xxx.xxx.xxx.ide</module>
        <module>xxx.xxx.xxx.ui</module>
        <module>xxx.xxx.xxx.target</module>
        <module>xxx.xxx.xxx.tests</module>
        <module>xxx.xxx.xxx.ui.tests</module>
        <module>xxx.xxx.xxx.services</module>
    </modules>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>xxx.xxx.xxx</groupId>
                            <artifactId>xxx.xxx.xxx.target</artifactId>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                        </artifact>
                    </target>
                    <environments>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                    </environments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.xtend</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xtend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${xtextVersion}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                                <goal>testCompile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/xtend-gen</outputDirectory>
                        <testOutputDirectory>${basedir}/xtend-gen</testOutputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>${basedir}/xtend-gen</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*</include>
                                </includes>
                                <directory>${basedir}/xtend-gen</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*</include>
                                </includes>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                        org.codehaus.mojo
                                    </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                        build-helper-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                        [1.9.1,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                                            <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore>
                                        </ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                        org.eclipse.tycho
                                    </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                        tycho-compiler-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                        [0.23.1,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore>
                                        </ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                        org.eclipse.tycho
                                    </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                        tycho-packaging-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                        [0.23.1,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>build-qualifier</goal>
                                            <goal>validate-id</goal>
                                            <goal>validate-version</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore>
                                        </ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <!-- 
                    Can be removed after first generator execution
                    https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=480097
                -->
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <compilerArgument>-err:-forbidden</compilerArgument>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

my target file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?>
<target name="com.psl.atom.target" sequenceNumber="1">
    <locations>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="planner" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.platform.feature.group" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.pde.feature.group" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.draw2d.feature.group" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.xpand" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.xtend" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.xtend.typesystem.emf" version="0.0.0" />
            <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/201506241002/" />
            <repository location="http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/mars" />
            <repository location="http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.2.1.2/mars/repository" />
            <repository location="http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.2.1.2/mars/repository/dependencies" />
        </location>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="planner" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launcher.feature.group" version="0.0.0" />
            <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emft/mwe/updates/releases/2.8.1/" />
        </location>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="planner" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
            <unit id="org.eclipse.xtext.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0" />
            <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/releases/2.9.1/" />
        </location>
    </locations>
</target>
```

Comment: I don't see a unit=... for the driver inside the target. And you should use a separate location tag for that.

Comment: I looked at MANIFEST of both bundles(for oracle 11 and oracle 12). Both of them contains  version-bundle=8.6.0, but in manifest i saw oracle.database.driver;bundle-version="8.6.0" oracle.database.driver11;bundle-version="8.6.0". When I changed manifest and use bundle for oracle 12. maven found mentioned bundle